# istio-ingressgateway failing with error "failed to generate workload certificate"

Tags: kubernetes, istio, kubeflow, istio-gateway

I'm seeing this error with `istio-ingressgateway` deployment when used this as part of Kubeflow 1.6.1 , this worked fine until some time and seeing issue recently .

```
2023-04-27T08:24:47.975252Z     info    Epoch 0 starting
2023-04-27T08:24:47.975316Z     info    Envoy command: [-c etc/istio/proxy/envoy-rev0.json --restart-epoch 0 --drain-time-s 45 --drain-strategy immediate --parent-shutdown-time-s 60 --local-address-ip-version v4 --file-flush-interval-msec 1000 --disable-hot-restart --log-format %Y-%m-%dT%T.%fZ        %l      envoy %n        %v -l warning --component-log-level misc:error]
2023-04-27T08:25:07.941486Z     warn    ca      ca request failed, starting attempt 1 in 98.23703ms
2023-04-27T08:25:08.040585Z     warn    ca      ca request failed, starting attempt 2 in 206.895191ms
2023-04-27T08:25:08.248146Z     warn    ca      ca request failed, starting attempt 3 in 408.67203ms
2023-04-27T08:25:08.657948Z     warn    ca      ca request failed, starting attempt 4 in 862.188035ms
2023-04-27T08:25:29.522844Z     warn    sds     failed to warm certificate: failed to generate workload certificate: create certificate: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: lookup istiod.istio-system.svc: i/o timeout"
2023-04-27T08:25:30.167267Z     warn    ca      ca request failed, starting attempt 1 in 106.340774ms
2023-04-27T08:25:30.274748Z     warn    ca      ca request failed, starting attempt 2 in 197.985129ms
2023-04-27T08:25:30.473287Z     warn    ca      ca request failed, starting attempt 3 in 382.393622ms
2023-04-27T08:25:30.855908Z     warn    ca      ca request failed, starting attempt 4 in 872.663691ms
2023-04-27T08:25:32.961176Z     warn    sds     failed to warm certificate: failed to generate workload certificate: create certificate: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: lookup istiod.istio-system.svc on 10.43.0.10:53: read udp 10.42.153.193:33022->10.43.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
2023-04-27T08:25:34.286620Z     warn    ca      ca request failed, starting attempt 1 in 95.465927ms
2023-04-27T08:25:34.383004Z     warn    ca      ca request failed, starting attempt 2 in 183.422432ms
2023-04-27T08:25:34.567594Z     warn    ca      ca request failed, starting attempt 3 in 420.81502ms
2023-04-27T08:25:34.989425Z     warn    ca      ca request failed, starting attempt 4 in 738.538305ms
2023-04-27T08:25:48.472256Z     warn    sds     failed to warm certificate: failed to generate workload certificate: create certificate: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: lookup istiod.istio-system.svc on 10.43.0.10:53: read udp 10.42.153.193:46532->10.43.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
2023-04-27T08:25:48.472666Z     warning envoy config    StreamAggregatedResources gRPC config stream closed since 40s ago: 14, connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: lookup istiod.istio-system.svc on 10.43.0.10:53: read udp 10.42.153.193:46532->10.43.0.10:53: read: connection refused"
```

I've tried redeploying the `istio-ingressgateway` to see if the certs are generated automatically , however still seeing the same error